# Is the Courier's Stash in Fallout New Vegas available if you already sold the items in one playthrough?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

So I got the DLC,I used the items till they were too under-powered for me and then sold them. Will I still be able to use them again in a different playthrough or am i screwed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they'll be there again when you start a new game. The DLC is not one-time-use.